# Class design and delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, delegates, sprite-kit

> 1) My GameScene which I the view where I have to add sknodes to the
>   scene for them to be viewed Has a wave manager that creates the first wave of enemies.
>
> 2) Wave manager. Creates and deletes waves, changes the next waves
>   parameters based on the previous wave. Has a reference to the current wave and can return it.
>
> 3) Wave Class. This class creates enemies on a timer, has all of the
>   logic for how enemies behave (flocking).

Every time I create an enemy in the wave I want to add it to the GameScene. The method that adds enemies to the wave is ran on a timer based on the game clock.

I tried to implement a delegate pattern so every time the method is called in the wave class then its delegate is called in GameScene. The problem is that my game scene doesn't have a a wave object in it so when I try call the method in the Wave class it won't do anything as the delegate is always null.

The delegate only works when I create an instance of Wave in GameScene then call the method with the code that executes one of the methods defined in the delegates protocol.

Are there any other design patterns I can follow so that whenever I call a method in Wave, a method or a draw function is called/updated in GameScene, bearing in mind my game scene does not know about the wave objects. It can only see the game manager.

Comment: Are you aware of `NSNotification` ? http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/06/06/delegation-or-notification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the delegate to the wave manager and it can pass it on to each wave as it's created. The delegate pattern is a 1:1 relationship but the delegate doesn't have to pass itself directly to the class which requires the delegate.

If more things than just the game scene are interested in new enemies appearing then posting notifications is suitable. Where delegate is 1:1, notifications are 1:many.

Another idea is to just pass the game scene as the parent node of all of the enemies. If you override `addChild:` in the game scene then you can check each new child and decide what to do...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. If I pass the delegate to the wave manager it still wouldn't work? As I don't call any extra methods on the wave object created in the manager, its all done from the constructor and the delegate seems to be nil at that point?

Comment: Could you explain the final idea in a little more detail please?

Comment: Similar to the delegate approach, passing the scene in the same way. But, instead of having a protocol, the wave just adds each new enemy using `addChild:`. The scene overrides `addChild:`, calling `super` first and then checking the child to see if it's an enemy and decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wealth of information on the internet and this site about how to use delegates as it seems to confuse people quite a bit.

Based on your question, I get the feeling that you are better off using a notification.

Why ?

Because you are just looking to notify the `GameScene` of some event that is occurring in a `Wave`. It's very simple to do that via a notification.

I strongly suggest you go to the link I posted in the comments :
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/06/06/delegation-or-notification.html

I believe it can help clear up many of the questions you have.

From that link you will find this logic in terms of deciding which to use :

*--Use delegates when you want the receiving object to influence an action that will happen to the sending object.
--Use notifications when you need to inform multiple objects of an event.*

Another key factor I see here is that you are not looking to call a method in the `GameScene` instance that returns any kind of data that might change your `Wave` instance's behavior or logic. If that was the case, I'd definitely use a delegate.

But it seems it's simply about "hey, I just did this... wanted you to know", and then the `GameScene` reacts with what it needs to do.

Also, it allows any other instance to be observing the same notification and act appropriately.

For instance your sound manager might react with a sound effect for the new wave. Your user interface might react by showing the text "Next wave is approaching". Your GameScene might increment it's currentWave property.

Whereas with the delegate route, you'd be going through all the hassle of setting up a delegate in each of those entities.